# how to get client's ip from jax-rs with restlet

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, restlet-2.0

How can i retrieve client's ip (the remote ip) of the http request?
I'm using JAX-RS with Restlet and not using servlets.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by [registering a custom request handler](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html#JAX-RSFilters-Overridingrequestandresponseproperties), here you will have access to request/response